# Flutter: Parse json arrays without name

Tags: arrays, json, flutter

I am getting json response from server as below.

```
[
    [{
        "ID": 1,
        "Date": "11-09-2015",
        "Balance": 1496693.00
    }, {
        "ID": 2,
        "Date": "01-10-2015",
        "Balance": 1496693.00
    }],
    [{
        "ID": 1,
        "Date": "03-09-2000",
        "IntAmount": "003.00"

    }],
    [{
        "EmployeeId": "000",
        "DesignationName": "deg"

    }],
    [{
        "LoanAmount": "00000.00",
        "IntRate": "3.00",
        "LoanNo": "56656"


    }]
]
```

I can parse json array with name but in above json there are three arrays without name.
How to parse above json in three different arrays?

Comment: [EXAMPLE IS HERE WITH DETAIL CODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917114/how-to-parse-json-without-key-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

If you are positive that the data will always come in the stated format, then you can iterate through the result. See below for example:

```
main(List<String> args) {

  // Define the array of data "object" like this

  List<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> arrayOfData = [
    [
      {"ID": 1, "Date": "11-09-2015", "Balance": 1496693.00},
      {"ID": 2, "Date": "01-10-2015", "Balance": 1496693.00}
    ],
    [
      {"ID": 1, "Date": "03-09-2000", "IntAmount": "003.00"}
    ],
    [
      {"EmployeeId": "000", "DesignationName": "deg"}
    ],
    [
      {"LoanAmount": "00000.00", "IntRate": "3.00", "LoanNo": "56656"}
    ]
  ];

  /* 
    Iterate through the array of "objects" using forEach,
    then, iterate through each resulting array using forEach
  */

  arrayOfData.forEach((datasetArray) => datasetArray.forEach((dataset) => print(dataset)));

  /* 
    ============== RESULT ========

    {ID: 1, Date: 11-09-2015, Balance: 1496693.0}
    {ID: 2, Date: 01-10-2015, Balance: 1496693.0}
    {ID: 1, Date: 03-09-2000, IntAmount: 003.00}
    {EmployeeId: 000, DesignationName: deg}
    {LoanAmount: 00000.00, IntRate: 3.00, LoanNo: 56656} 

  */

}
```